# How do you compare Java array index elements with characters?

Tags: java, arrays

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        String ox = in.next();
                
        String[] oxline = ox.split("");
        


        for (int i = 0; i < oxline.length; i++) {
            
        if (**oxline[i] == "O"**) {
            System.out.println("it work");
        } else {
            
        }

        }
```

I can't compare the index element with the char.

How can you compare the letter "O" with the O in the index of the array?

Comment: You can compare true chars using `==`, but not Strings which are reference type. They require use of the `.equals(...)` or `.equalsIgnoreCase(...)` methods.

Comment: So, `if (oxline.toCharArray[i] == 'O') {...` should also work

Comment: Agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels, but if you're programming in java, use the methods from StrIng class, at least that's the best way of doing it in java.